# Good resource to learn scientific Chinese

Tags: resources, terminology

I'm searching for a good resource to learn Chinese with a focus on natural sciences and engineering. In particular, I would like the name of chemicals, machinery parts and environmental/ecological concepts.

Comment: To add a bit of background: When I learnt Russian I used a book written by a scientist and for scientists: the examples were all from natural science or engineering (e.g. a chapter on the logic behind names of chemicals). It also taught grammar in a systematic way that I found very useful. So I am searching for something similar for Chinese. If that is if any importance I'm a beginner, but I wrote the question in a broad way in case somebody else was searching for that too.

The book  is “Manuel de Russe à l’usage des scientifiques”, from Y. Gentilhomme (no English version as far as I know)

Comment: web search using "自然科学词典" yields http://www.onedict.com/subject.php?qw=%E8%87%AA%E7%84%B6%E7%A7%91%E5%AD%A6 with parallel English and Chinese definitions

Comment: Thank you, that could be useful. However, I am more looking for a resource like an app or a book, which I could refer to when I want to learn about or train a specific topic. I am not searching for an online dictionary or translator

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/VqHL2Suc39czUv (click on image to get pdf of entire book)
Кочергин И.В. Основы научно-технического перевода с китайского на русский.pdf （Foundations of scientific-technological translation from Chinese to Russian)

Comment: I just had a look. This seems indeed a good resource, I'll keep it in my library. I can read it but maybe others might prefer an English course book. Anyway, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I know of a couple resources for medicine and chemistry. These are technical dictionaries. You can start checking these out. I used to use them for work and never had problems so I guess the translations should be correct. Will post more as I come across them.

*Medicine*:
[drdict.com](http://www.drdict.com/)

*Chemistry*:
[cosdna.com](http://www.cosdna.com/chs/stuff.php)

**EDIT:**
If you're looking for occasional term references, usually a good bet is to search Wikipedia and switch to the Chinese page.

Answer (score 0):

推荐几个中文Podcast：

**《科学脱口秀》**
RSS: http://www.kexuetuokouxiu.com/feed/podcast

科学脱口秀是一个主要以科学相关的谈话类节目，植物学，天文学，两性的等等

**《太医来了》**
太医来了 是医学、健康相关的节目

RSS: http://ipn.li/taiyilaile/feed

**《心理开花》**
心理开花 是心理学相关的节目，听这个节目可以学到很多心理学的概念。

以上节目可以在itunes中搜索订阅到.